# I need help with this series

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{999} \frac{1}{(n+1) \sqrt n+n \sqrt{n+1}}$

I am not sure how to start. can someone help me with this question?

Comment: What is it that you want to do? Compute it? Do you have any thoughts of your own on the problem?

Comment: Hi. I manage to sum from n=1 to n=3 and I get 0.5. however my goal is to evaluate the summation. I can't seems to find the correct pattern. Which direction should I be looking from?

Comment: Well, if you really can't think of anything cleverer to do, you could always resort old fashioned addition.

Comment: I could but this is a 10 mins exercise challenge. I am looking to learn a more efficient of solving this series. Thank you

Comment: $S_{999}=1-\dfrac{\sqrt{10}}{100}$

Comment: @user140852 Sure, but in my experience often the best way to learn a more efficient way of doing things is to first try the inefficient brute force way, because that's how notice details that help explain what's so inefficient about the inefficient way. It's hard to pick up on patterns if you don't look =)

Comment: @Lucian May I know how do you get S(999) = 1 - sqrt(10)/100?

Comment: @DavidH Yup I understand. Actually. I am still doing it until n=5 so far. There are 999 numbers I need to substitute.lol

Comment: $S\big(N^2-1\big)=1-\dfrac1N\iff S(N)=1-\dfrac1{\sqrt{N+1}}$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

Start multiplying both numeator and denominator by
$$ (n+1) \sqrt n-n \sqrt{n+1}$$ and simplify as much as you can. I suppose that you could face a telescopic series and this should simplify the problem.

Comment: +1 but it looks bleak. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(1%2F(nsqrt(n%2B1)%2Bsqrt(n)(n%2B1)))+from+n%3D1+to+999

Comment: Yea I did use Wolfram alpha but I don't want the final answer actually. I need to understand a more efficient way of doing it and getting the final on my own. Thank you

Comment: @Claude Leibovici If I do that. the numerator becomes (n+1sqrt(n) - n sqrt(n+1) ) How do I continue from there? I manage to simplfy the denominator to (n)(n+1)(2n+1)

Comment: Better yet, start by noticing that $(n+1) \sqrt n+n \sqrt{n+1}=\sqrt{n+1}\sqrt n (\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n)$ and only rationalize the part in parentheses. This makes the telescopic nature of the summand immediately transparent.

Comment: David H Oh wow. Thank you very much David. I appreciate you taking your time to response to help me! I feel like I have an idea to evaluate this. I am going to take some time to solve this. Thank you very much!